# Paypal Digital Goods with no floating box but redirect to paypal site

Tags: paypal

I'm using Paypal Digital Goods, it is good until now. When user click on button, it open a floating box with paypal iframe.

The problem is I don't want using floating box anymore. I stop using paypal javascript. After call a request to paypal

```
$nvps["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
$nvps["RETURNURL"] = $this->configs['return_url'];
$nvps["CANCELURL"] = $this->configs['cancel_url'];
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL"] = $this->configs['listener_url'];
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = $item['price'];
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = $item['currency'];
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = $item['price'];
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"] = $item['desc'];
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0"] = $item_number;
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"] = $item['price'];
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"] = "1";
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0"] = "Digital";
```

I redirect to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=" with a token from request above. The style of page is still like a floating box. If user click on login button, it still open a mini browser (popup) and I don't want like this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply stop loading the dg.js fil and change the PayPal redirection URL from https://www.paypal.com/incontext?token= to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=
This will make it the regular Express Checkout checkout experience.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are still including the Paypal dg.js file.  Remove the following line from your page and the Paypal iFrame will no longer appear.

```
<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: I removed it. And it open on a whole page now. But it style still look like a model box, not a full paypal webpage. And when use click on login button, it open a mini popup.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing code between PayPal products.  Your call to paypal.com/incontext should be www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr, and I think the $nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"] method is for incontext payments only.

Comment: Does any method for digital good which the whole process will on paypal site, when cancel or success payment will redirect to my website?